# Map control within Listbox

Tags: wpf

I am trying to display multiple maps within an Listbox.

```
        <Grid Name="MainGrid">
            <ScrollViewer  HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >
                <WrapPanel Name="wrap" >
                    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel>
                                <Border Margin="5" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="400" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black"
                                  Width="200" 
                                  Height="200" >
                                    <esri:MapView  MouseDown="MapView_MouseDown" MouseUp="MapView_MouseUp"  >
                                        <esri:Map   >
                                            <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer ID="BaseMap" ServiceUri="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer"/>
                                        </esri:Map>
                                    </esri:MapView>
                                </Border>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListBox>
                </WrapPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
```

The map does not get displayed. Only the logo "esri" gets displayed. But if I remove the listbox, it works fine. What could be the issue?

I am very sure that there are items in my listbox otherwise "esri" would not have appeared. 
I have tried Itemscontrol as well but its the same result.

Comment: You have set the width and height of parent container as 200 px. A question here - Does zoom in/out functionality work?

Comment: Sorry but what which control is the "parent container"? As I said if I removed the listbox, Itemtemplate and Datatemplate, the map is displayed

Answer (score 0):

In WPF, we don't put UI elements into collections, we put *data* objects into collections. Each data item should contain whichever properties are needed to data bind to the UI control that you actually want to display. So your `MyList` collection should contain a collection of data objects.

Once you have created a custom class to contain these required properties, you will then need to declare a `DataTemplate` that defines which UI element(s) to display. (See the [Data Templating Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms742521(v=vs.100).aspx) page on MSDN for further information on this).

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="YourCustomControlTemplate">
    <!-- Define your UI content here -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

Once you have declared your custom `ControlTemplate` for your custom data class, you should then put it into a `Style` for your data object:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type YourXamlPrefix:YourCustomDataClass}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource YourCustomControlTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Note that I have omitted the `x:Key` directive on this `Style`... you *can* add one, but without one (and as long as this `Style` has been declared in scope of the UI), the `Style` will be automatically applied to your data objects in the collection.